# React Native with axios - Network error calling localhost with self signed https endpoint

Tags: react-native, axios

I created service in Visual Studio with Conveyor extension to make it accessible in local network. I installed certificate on my Android device so there is green padlock when calling it in browser and service works fine.
However when calling it from React Native app with axios then i get Network error.
That's my code:

```
    const fetchData = async () => {
      console.log('url', `${Settings.API_URL}/location/GetDataByMyIp`);
      try {
        const result = await axios(
          `${Settings.API_URL}/location/GetDataByMyIp`,
        );
        console.log('result', result);
        ipData = {
          city: result.data.city,
          longitude: result.data.longitude,
          latitude: result.data.latitude,
        };
      } catch (e) {
        console.log('error', e);
      }
    };
    await fetchData();
```

In console i see:

```
url https://192.168.1.14:45455/api/location/GetDataByMyIp
error Error: Network Error
    at createError (path_to_app\node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16)
    at EventTarget.handleError (path_to_app\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\xhr.js:83)
    at EventTarget.dispatchEvent (path_to_app\node_modules\event-target-shim\dist\event-target-shim.js:818)
    at EventTarget.setReadyState (path_to_app\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:575)
    at EventTarget.__didCompleteResponse (path_to_app\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:389)
    at path_to_app\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:502
    at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (path_to_app\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\vendor\emitter\EventEmitter.js:189)
    at MessageQueue.__callFunction (path_to_app\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:425)
    at path_to_app\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:112
    at MessageQueue.__guard (path_to_app\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:373)
```

I tried to add this line to AndroidManifest.xml application tag but still have the error

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Some solutions say about adding as 2nd parameter to axios, but it doesn't work with React Native.

```
new https.Agent({
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
});
```

I tried to call some other service from the internet and then error was gone.

Is there some solution to this? I haven't found anything more. My last idea is to host service on Azure so I'll have properly signed SSL, but i guess it has to be a way to run it locally.

Edit: It works through http

Comment: see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/74087759/3732075